# Can insmod and rmmod for one module be triggered from another module's Driver?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

We are trying to get insmod and rmmod of one module to work from another module's ioctl on a condition ; Is this possible ? If not, is there any way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the manual page for `modprobe` it allows you to intelligently add and remove modules to the kernel, and can be configured.